# OneDrive API Unauthenticated

Tags: python, onedrive

I am trying to use the OneDrive api to get a list of files from a folder that I've just created for testing reasons.
First I get the access token like this:

```
import requests

data = {'client_id': 'my_client_id', 
         'scope': 'the scope',
         'client_secret': 'the client value',
         'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}

headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Host": "login.microsoftonline.com"}

# and then I request the data
result = requests.get("https://login.microsoftonline.com/the-tenant-id/oauth2/v2.0/token", data=data, headers= headers)

# This provides the access_token

access_token = result.json()['access_token']
```

Now when I try to do any request I use the following headers:

```
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'bearer ' + access_token,
}
```

But I am always getting the following (or similar) error:

```
{'error': {'code': 'unauthenticated', 'message': "Must be authenticated to use '/drive' syntax."}}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50056414/12715723

Comment: Have you tried change `requests.get` to `requests.post`?